# Adding a new Operation Contract in Service Contract won't expose if browsing via IIS

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, wsdl

I have a strange problem.

I added a new Operation Contract in my existing WCF Service Contract. I am hosting it in local IIS. When I browse my service via IIS the new OC doesn't appear. But when I launch the service via Visual Studio I can see the new OC.

I don't understand why IIS is not exposing the new OC while it exposes the old ones.

In the WSDL generated via IIS, the new OC disappears.
In the WSDL generated via VS, the new OC appears.

Thanks

Comment: Did you create a backup of bin folder and overwrite the files? Try to delete the bin content e try again, it must throw an error, because will miss the assemblies. Then try to copy the files again.

Comment: tried but not helpful

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting IIS? My guess would be that when you look at this in Visual Studio, VS is starting a web server instance as a container for you to look at that is separate from your IIS instance. Restarting IIS should make IIS re-read your files, and hopefully put it in the same state as you see in VS.

Obviously restarting IIS may not be an acceptable long term solution for a production environment, so you will probably want to find a better solution going forward. This may, however show you where your problem is.

Comment: I restarted my IIS several times but not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha...

During publishing just changed release to debug.

Worked fine.